# Dynamically added views do not reset?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout in which I am adding some CheckBoxes dynamically, they are adding perfectly well on first call, when I am calling the same method with different values, then they are not appearing in that LinearLayout, old values are not getting replaced with new values.

I checked values in LogCat and they seem fine, whatever I'm passing is being displayed in LogCat but not appearing in LinearLayout.

Here's my method that adds the view:

```
private void setOptions(int questionID2) {
        ArrayList<String> options = pustakDB.getOptions(questionID2);
        Log.e("optionsInAct", options.toString() + " size " + options.size());

        OptionView = new LinearLayout(this);
        OptionView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, img.getId());
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, questionNumber.getId());
        rel.addView(OptionView, p);

        int i = 0;
        while (i < options.size()) {
            CheckBox c = new CheckBox(this);
            c.setText(options.get(i));
            c.setId(i);
            OptionView.addView(c);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Edit: "rel" here is RelativeLayout.

Comment: Do you add these views to the Dialog or to the Activity?

Comment: I defined a RelativeLayout in Activity. Adding views in RelativeLayoyt.

Comment: "they are not appearing in that `LinearLayout`", do you mean `OptionView`? You are defining a new LinearLayout each time `setOption` method is being invoked, that is why your added views are not on the same `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I thought I should create new LinearLayout to make old entries go away. Let me compile again.

Comment: you can call `removeAllView()` for removing old entries.

Comment: I'm calling removeAll on optionView, but I'm getting IllegalStateExcepption with Logcat: 10-01 13:49:47.149: E/AndroidRuntime(1080): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Thanks @Aprian it finally worked :) . Long live SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // put this somewhere else
    OptionView = new LinearLayout(this);
    OptionView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, img.getId());
    p.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, questionNumber.getId());
    rel.addView(OptionView, p);


private void setOptions(int questionID2) {
    ArrayList<String> options = pustakDB.getOptions(questionID2);
    Log.e("optionsInAct", options.toString() + " size " + options.size());

    // this will remove all views from OptionView
    OptionView.removeAllViews();

    int i = 0;
    while (i < options.size()) {
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox(this);
        c.setText(options.get(i));
        c.setId(i);
        OptionView.addView(c);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Try this and see if it works.

Comment: I edited bit of your code. CHanged it to what really worked for me.

Comment: you don't really need to remove the `OptionView` from the `rel` and readding it again to `rel`. You should only add one time to `rel` and that's it.